# Find a sufficient statistic for this parameter of a Pareto distibution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I've got a problem with the following exercise:

Let be the following function a distribution:

$$f_{\theta,a}(x)=\begin{cases}
\theta a^\theta x^{-(\theta+1)} &, x\geq a\\
0 &, x<a
\end{cases}$$
while $a,\theta>0$.

1. Find a sufficient statistic for $a$, while $\theta$ is known.
2. Find a sufficient statistic for $\theta$, while $a$ is known.

Could give me a solution for the first sufficient statistic, please?

Comment: Can you state the likelihood given the observations $x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n$? Remember to take account of the support.

Comment: Is that a proper density? I cannot see that  $\displaystyle \int_{x=a}^\infty \tfrac1\theta x^{-(\theta-1)}\, dx =1$ is necessarily true. A Pareto distribution would have density  $\theta a^\theta x^{-(\theta+1)}$ for $x\ge a$

Comment: Sorry @Henry. Yes, it's a Pareto distribution. The sufficient statistic for $\theta$ is $\prod_{i=1}^n x_i$. But how can I find a sufficient statistic for $a$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the likelihood function using [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) to show the dependence on $a$:

$$L(\theta, a) = \prod _{i=1}^n \theta \frac {a^\theta} {x_i^{\theta+1}}[x_i\ge a] = \theta^n a^{n\theta} \prod _{i=1}^n \frac {1}{x_i^{\theta+1}}\prod _{i=1}^n [x_i \ge a].$$

But
$$\prod_{i=1}^n [x_i \ge a] = [(\min_i x_i) \ge a] 
$$

so

$$L(\theta, a)  = \theta^n a^{n\theta} \left(\prod _{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{-(\theta+1)} [(\min_i x_i) \ge a].
$$

Therefore, $(\prod _{i=1}^n x_i)$ and $(\min_i x_i)$ are sufficient statistics for $\theta$ and $a$, respectively.

Comment: So you can write $\displaystyle \theta^n a^{n\theta} \prod _{i=1}^n \frac {1}{x_i^{\theta+1}}\prod _{i=1}^n [x_i \ge a] = \theta^n a^{n\theta} \left(\prod _{i=1}^n x_i\right)^{-(\theta+1)} I[\min_i x_i \ge a]$ which makes it a little clearer that $\prod  x_i$ is sufficient for $\theta$ and $\min x_i$ sufficient for $a$.

Comment: @Henry - True, but I was focusing on $a$; nevertheless, I will edit to improve -- thanks.